# Can't mount Android Things image file in OS X to tweak config files

Tags: macos, filesystems, android-things

Some tutorials recommend making modifications to files such as `wpa_supplicant.conf` within the Android Things image file, as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41732035/766115. I'm trying with the Android Things developer preview 4.1 image file.

However, I've had no luck mounting this file for editing purposes on OS X. Various attempts to use os x Disk Utility or the `mount` command from the terminal all result in some type of error message telling me the file format is not compatible. I can see in Disk Util, or through terminal mount, that the ISO image has 15 sectors (or partitions), but I can't access them.

I've even tried spinning up an Ubuntu in AWS, uploading and mounting from there. No dice.

```
   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Any advice? What am I missing.

Comment: What does your syslog say?  Where is this ISO file?  How exactly did you try mounting it?  I'm not sure how to debug this if I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Alternatively, if no luck, and in case you have a [USB to TTL cable](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954), you could [connect to serial debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339) and edit `wpa_supplicant.conf` on the device (using `echo`). The answer referred contains solutions for `Ubuntu` and `Windows` OSs though, but you're very welcome to provide one for `Mac` OS.

Comment: I'm trying to mount the Android Things image, specifically Android Things dev preview 4.1.

Answer (score 4):

On macOS I have done this way:

1. Connect the sdcard on your Mac
2. Run on terminal `diskutil list` and see the name of your sdcard (in my case `/dev/disk2s1`)
3. Create a directory where the sdcard will be mounted: `sudo mkdir -p /Volumes/pisdcard`
4. Mount the sdcard: `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/pisdcard`
5. Edit what you want and unmount the sdcard with: `sudo umount /dev/disk2s1`

It worked for me, I used to change `config.txt` and `cmdline.txt` to change UART mode and use a GPS module on Android Things.

Answer (score 1):

`hdiutil attach [file]` is the macOS command to treat an image file as a disk device. If the image file contains a filesystem macOS can read, it should also mount any volumes contained in the file. If your image contains a volume not supported by macOS (e.g., ext4), you also need to install an appropriate driver before you can mount the volume.

Comment: Same as with Disk Utility, this returns the following error message `hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems`