# Android Things - Setup with Laptop only

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Is this possible? I've no LAN cable, no USB to TLL cable and want to connect my raspberry pi 3 with my WLAN.

I've found this: [How to set wifi to Android Things without an ethernet cable or adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731108/how-to-set-wifi-to-android-things-without-an-ethernet-cable-or-adb) but I can't boot the img file (https://developer.android.com/things/preview/download.html) and edit it. If I boot it on windows 10, it tells me errorenous image. If I boot it with a third party app like `OSFMount` I can boot it, but the content looks like opening the sd card after flashing the image, like following:

[image]

So no `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file that I could edit... Am I mounting it wrong?

Any ideas on how to get this working without buying something? All I need to do is setting up the WLAN on the sd card directly somehow...

Comment: I'm afraid you have only 2 options: mount the image on your `Windows` machine to edit `wpa_supplicant.conf` or buy additional stuff...

Comment: Then I'm stuck at mounting it. Any ideas how to do it? Windows 10 should be able to mount images, but it says the image is errorenous (although the flashed image works, I tested it, android things boots up if I connect it with a scrren). Mounting it with OSFMount works without errors, but the mounted drives content looks the same as the sd cards content. Any ideas?

Comment: Did You try [flashing image on SD card](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html), then insert SD card to card reader on Win 10 PC and edit?

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko yes I did. The screenshot shows the content of the sd card after flashing the image...

Comment: This is the `RPIBOOT` partition in the picture you've posted. You should look for the file on the `/` partition.

Comment: For the Pi, if you don't have a Lan cable the USB to TTY is something you really should get. It makes it a lot easier to debug things and work with the Pi, especially when you don't have ethernet access.

Comment: @Onik thanks, that info helped. I just can't mount the image on windows, all apps I tried show wrong data, errors or nothing. Tried a virtual machine now with linux and there I could successfully mount it (although I could not mount it with write permissions yet), but at least I can see the `/` path and it's content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to successfully AND correctly mount all partitions on windows. A virtual machine with ubuntu helped mounting everything, but I could only mount it successfully with read permissions.

Final solution: I bought a UST to TTL cable, connected via putty to my raspberry pi and set up wifi via the console...

It's somehow sad, that there is no setup file on the boot partition (like the `cmdline.txt` and `confix.txt` file) that could simply be added, this would make things a lot easier...

Comment: Hmm. If you have ubuntu you should be able to mount it write as well??? I do remember a virtual box (???) workaround to access partitions though.

Comment: Since you will contextually only have 1 main app, I would suggest that your main app will have the option to connect to available wifi network. After you adding that funcionality, simply generate your apk-build, then upload to your android things project console, and include it your own bundle (your main apk, any other apk that you could use from your main app, bootanimation.zip). And additional apk suh as Terminal Emulator are pretty useful. Then, you can download your android things image that pre-came with your own bundle, and write it on your sd card

Comment: Here is the link to create your own Android Things image that pre-build with your own bundle --> [Android Things Console](https://partner.android.com/things/console/)