# Android Things: connect to WiFi without cables

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi3, android-wifi, android-things, wifi

How to connect to *WiFi* my *Raspberry Pi* 3 with *Android Things* version 0.5.1. I've mounted SD card and current the /misc/wifi directory is

```
wifi> ls
drwxrwx--- 2  1010  1010 4096 1970-01-01  hostapd
drwxrwx--- 2  1010  1010 4096 1970-01-01  sockets
-rw------- 1 jacek jacek   46 2009-01-01  softap.conf
-rw------- 1 jacek jacek  236 2009-01-01  WifiConfigStore.xml
drwxrwx--- 2  1010  1010 4096 10-29 15:09 wpa_supplicant
```

where the `wpa_supplicant`, `hostapd`, `sockets` directories are empty.

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41732035 there should be a file `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

I dont't have any cables so this is my last chance to get it working.

I think *WiFi* configuration is stored in `WifiConfigStore.xml`, but I dont't know what fields I should add.

Contents of `WifiConfigStoreData.xml` is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<WifiConfigStoreData>
<int name="Version" value="1" />
<NetworkList />
<PasspointConfigData>
<long name="ProviderIndex" value="0" />
</PasspointConfigData>
</WifiConfigStoreData>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've never executed `adb shell am startservice -n com.google.wifisetup...` within your `RPi3`'s `shell` then the `/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant` directory is empty.

Simply creating a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file in the mounted on your host machine SD card isn't enough as the file, similar to the `/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant` directory, should be `own`ed and `group`ed by the system service's process which is `1010` in your `ls` command result:

```
drwxrwx--- 2  1010  1010 4096 10-29 15:09 wpa_supplicant
```

Yet I recommend to [connect your *RPi3* either over Ethernet or USB-to-TTL cable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988431/3290339).